# Terminal shows "~" when pressing DEL

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-terminal

On Ubuntu (9.10) I have the problem that when I open a terminal (standard gnome terminal), the <kbd>del</kbd> key does not work. Instead it print a `~` character. When I open an new tab, it most of the time is resolved in this old tab, but not in the new one.

What can be the thing that is causing this? The gnome terminal compatibility settings are "ASCII DEL" for the backspace key and "Automatic" for the delete key.

One thing I noticed, when I ssh into a machine in a different network (with different account/bashrc etc.) the <kbd>del</kbd> key starts working. When I ssh into a machine here in the network with the same account/bashrc/bash_profile it still doesn't work.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read "[Consistent BackSpace and Delete Configuration](http://www.ibb.net/~anne/keyboard.html)", especially the section about "[Bash](http://www.ibb.net/~anne/keyboard/keyboard.html#Bash)":

```
"\e[3~": delete-char
```

try to put that to your .bashrc.

Comment: I just copied all the suggested code into `.inputrc`. Thanks for the help!